# Need to extract a specific attribute value from a delimited string

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to extract a specific value from the column.
output of my table is:

```
select * from table where id='123456'
```

This table has around 30 columns, out of which I need to check for the word in specific column say "column 1". the data in the column 1 is:

```
Test1=Hi;Test2=Hello;Test3=Good;Test4=Morning`
```

Question: I need a query that extracts only specific word from the column "Test2", i.e output should be the value of Test2 i.e. `Hello` (I need Hello should only print as output)

Comment: You should do `select Column1 from table where id='123456'` if you don't need all the columns data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use (since 11g) REGEXP_SUBSTR to return the match you need

```
WITH test AS (SELECT 'Test1=Hi;Test2=Hello;Test3=Good;Test4=Morning' AS column_1 FROM DUAL)
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(column_1, 'Test2=(.+?);', 1, 1, NULL, 1) FROM test;
```

Answer (score 1):

i have to get that test2 is a value so i changed my query use like operator

```
select * from table where id='123456' and col1 like 'Test2=Hello%'
```

Comment: But Test2 is not a column name, it's present under column among other entries, see below example:
"column 1". the data in the column 1 is :

Test1=Hi;Test2=Hello;Test3=Good;Test4=Morning

Comment: @SaipraveenBellary use like operator

Comment: thanks for the reply, but output should be "Hello" only, in your query it will fetch the all the records. but i need only Hello should come as output.

Comment: @SaipraveenBellary can you please share full structure with sample data then it will be more easy to help

Answer (score 0):

Try this : This will search string only... for specific column i think need to case statement.

```
DECLARE @String AS VARCHAR(10) = 'Hello'

SELECT * FROM a WHERE @String IN ( test1, test2, test3, test4, test5 )
```

Comment: Well, this won't work in Oracle (and the OP tagged the question as such).